# Can we integrate Gherkin feature files with testcomplete

Tags: testcomplete, gherkin

Can we integrate Gherkin feature files with TestComplete

Is there is an available plugin for TestComplete with Gherkin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TestComplete does not support Gherkin feature files. However, TestComplete has [SDK](http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing-tools/testcomplete-extensions-and-sdk/) so it is possible to create an extension for this by yourself.